# The 104.238.72.167:2083 page isn’t working

Tags: serve

I am trying to connect to the remote host server to acess the cpanel but the link`The 104.238.72.167:2083/` not working .But the same addreass is working on other computer.Plz help me how to sort this problem

Comment: Did you deactivate your Windows Firewall to test it?

Comment: yes i did but still not working.

Comment: Maybe you set up a proxy connection in that browser? Or the pc is in a different network maybe administrated by someone else? Our firewall at work for example would block that port.

Comment: Looks like that URL requires HTTPS: https://104.238.72.167:2083